# iPhone - Updating Annotation subtitle in mapkit

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotation, reverse-geocoding

I have a custom placemark with title and subtitle. The subtitle is actually displaying the address of the dropped pin using the reverse geocoder.

I have a button which has an action to drop the pin. This action gets the location coordinates of the user, and then calls [geocoder start] which gets the full address with Reverse Geocoder and generates the custom annotation and then calls [mapView addAnnotation:customPlacemark].

My problem is that using this sequence order, when there's no a WiFi connection (only 3G or maybe Edge) the pin takes a lot to drop because it's watigin to get the reverse geocoding info.

So basically I need to drop the pin without a subtitle and from the viewDidAnnotation call the geocoder and inside the reverseGeocoder update the subtitle but I'm not sure how to do that.

I want to display the annotation without the address details and update it when it gets the information from the reverse geocoder.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MKMapView` observes changes its annotations via KVO. Therefore if you update your annotation's properties in a KVO compliant manner, it should Just Work.

For example, when the reverse geocoder returns an address for your annotation, you first announce the `title` and `subtitle` properties are about to change:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
```

Note that the above code is assumed to be in the annotation class.

Then update the annotation with information from the geocoder. When you are done:

```
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
```

Note the order changed for `didChangeValueForKey:` as these need to be nested properly, somewhat like HTML tags.

This also works for the `coordinate` property, that will cause the pin to move.

Comment: So in the reverseGeocoder I don't even need to create a new customPlacemark object?
Using [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"] how it knows I'm refering to my custom Placemark annotation?

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: If it wasn't clear from the examples, that method is called from within the annotation class, so the `self` is the annotation added to the map view. You can do this in your reverse geocoder by finding the correct annotation (Placemark), and calling `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` on the instance.

Comment: I'll try this tonight and tell you how it goes. Thanks =)

Comment: Ok, I'm feeling like a stupid now. I'm trying to get the correct annotation as you mention but I don't realize how todo it. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Sure, try making the annotation the reverse geocoder's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd place the annotation, keep a reference to it in a property, then when your reverse geocoder calls back use the reference to the annotation and update its properties.