# How do I update a callout view without deselecting the annotation?

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

The only way I've found so far to update the text in an already visible callout bubble is to deselect its annotation and then selecting it again, like this:

```
id <MKAnnotation> annotation = self.selectedAnnotation; // Keep a reference
[self.mapView deselectAnnotation:self.selectedAnnotation animated:NO];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
```

This approach, however, is causing some unwanted side-effects in my app.

Does anyone know of any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean the standard callout view that shows title and subtitle?  How are you updating title and subtitle in the code?  If you update the text using the standard property setter (eg. `ann.title = @"changed";`) the callout should be updated without a deselect+select.

Comment: Yes, I use the standard property setter (although indirectly, since title and subtitle are readonly), but in a method that I've defined myself, so I guess the deselect+select trick works by invoking some method that re-creates the callout. Do you know which method that might be?

Comment: If you set title and subtitle directly using a setter, the callout will update automatically because the map view observes the change via KVO.  If you can't update directly, you'll need to manually call willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey before/after the change (instead of the deselect+select).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705678/iphone-updating-annotation-subtitle-in-mapkit.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you Anna, this solved my problem =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anna provided a perfect solution in the comments to my question!

By explicitly informing the MKMapView (which listens for changes via KVO) of the text change, I managed to get the callout to update, which it otherwise wouldn't. Here's the working code:

```
[annotation willChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
annotation.subTitle = @"New subtitle";
// subTitle is the property behind MKAnnotation's subtitle
[annotation didChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
```

Thank you Anna for coming to the rescue =)